# Will this code replace the existing database file with new file or not?

Tags: java, android

I'm copying my db file to sd car using this methode please tell me if file at sdcard is already existing then whether it will replace or will not copy?

```
public boolean copyDbToSDCard() {
        boolean success = false;
        String SDCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath();
        final String DBPATH = SDCardPath + "/BD/";
        final String DBNAME = "Mydb3.db";
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        File directory = new File(DBPATH);
        if (!directory.exists())
            directory.mkdir();
        close();

        try {
            InputStream mInput = new FileInputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DBPATH + DBNAME);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = mInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                mOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            mOutput.flush();
            mOutput.close();
            mInput.close();
            success = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(myContext,
                    "copyDbToSDCard Error : " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.fillInStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: How about testing your code instead of asking if it works? It is almost way faster and does not waste our time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check is database available or not ?

like this

```
checkDB()
{
try{
      SQLiteDatabase   dbe = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("selectedFilePath", null,0);
        Log.d("opendb","EXIST");
        dbe.close();
         // DB exits then delete
        File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
        boolean deleted = file.delete(); <--- this will help you to delete DB

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         // DB not exits code to copy database
    }
 }
```

Comment: and my target is sdcard not data data package dbname

Answer (score 1):

the code:

```
OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DBPATH + DBNAME);
```

and

```
mOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
```

makes that if the file exists it will replace the content of the file with the new data

Comment: I've just tested similar code, and the file is overwrited with the new content

Comment: If you want to append a file via FileOutputStream, you have to explicitly tell it in the constructor:  new FileOutputStream(file, true);

Comment: but what if none of the data matched in both file